# Create QR codes with a SVG border template using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, image-processing, qr-code

I'm using the Python qrcode library to generate a SVG QR code:

```py
factory = qrcode.image.svg.SvgImage
img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white", image_factory=factory)
```

And I've a separate SVG image (border.svg). How can I integrate the QR code object (img) into the border svg to produce one combined svg file? I've found a lot of svg libraries to convert to png/eps, but none of them is able to simply integreate two images.

Bonus: The border (or the QR image) must be scaled to fit because depending on the data size for the QR code, the dimension of the QR svg varies.

Comment: What is border.svg like, is it a pattern that needs to be copyed around the QR code or is it square of the boarder with a blank spot for the QR code?

Comment: Its a square with a blank spot.

Answer (score 0):

I did some spelunking for python SVG module and I didn't come up with anything that made the problem simpler.

SVG is actually just XML. So you can edit the XML of the SVG and change the SVG. Python does have good build in support for XML (really *ML).

The basic idea is to take the boarder and get its size. With size we then scale the qr code to fit inside the boarder. Then we take qr and add it to the boarder SVG-XML and save to new file.

```py
from lxml import etree

# Create XML objects
boarder = etree.parse('boarder.svg')
qr = etree.parse('qr.svg') # ET.parse('qr.svg').getroot()

# Get size of boarder
Bhight = int(boarder.xpath('//*[local-name()="svg"]/@width')[0])
Bwidth = int(boarder.xpath('//*[local-name()="svg"]/@height')[0])
# Make sure that it is a square
assert(Bhight == Bwidth)

# resize qr code for boarder.
qrBack = qr.xpath('//*[local-name()="svg"]//*[local-name()="g"]//*[local-name()="rect"]')[0]

# Also needs to be a square
assert(qrBack.attrib['height'] == qrBack.attrib['width'])

# Calc offset code from boarder
qrWidth = int(qrBack.attrib['width'])
offset = (Bwidth - qrWidth) / 2

# Add offset attribute
qr.xpath('//*[local-name()="svg"]//*[local-name()="g"]')[0].attrib['transform'] = 'translate({0},{0})'.format(offset)

# get qr code
QRC = qr.xpath('//*[local-name()="svg"]//*[local-name()="g"]')[0]
# Take Boarder as xml root
root = boarder.getroot()
# Add QRC to root
root.append(QRC)
# Write new svg to file
with open( 'boarder+qr.svg', 'w' ) as f:
    f.write( etree.tostring( root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8', standalone="yes").decode() )
```

Creates file `boarder+qr.svg`.

For reference:

boarder.svg

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   height="110"
   width="110">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <path
       id="rect1379"
       d="m 0,0 h 110 v 110 H 0 Z 0"
       style="
          stroke:#FFFFFF;
          stroke-width:0.89999998;
          stroke-linecap:round;
          stroke-linejoin:round;
          stroke-miterlimit:4;
          stroke-dasharray:none;
          stroke-dashoffset:0;
          stroke-opacity:1"
          />
  </g>
</svg>
```

qr.svg

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="99" height="99" version="1.1"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <desc>Zint Generated Symbol
   </desc>

   <g id="barcode" fill="#000000">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#FFFFFF" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="12.00" width="21.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="12.00" width="12.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="54.00" y="12.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="12.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="12.00" width="21.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="45.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="51.00" y="15.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="18.00" y="18.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="39.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="51.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="57.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="72.00" y="18.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="18.00" y="21.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="45.00" y="21.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="57.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="72.00" y="21.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="18.00" y="24.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="45.00" y="24.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="72.00" y="24.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="27.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="48.00" y="27.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="30.00" width="21.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="42.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="48.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="54.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="30.00" width="21.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="33.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="57.00" y="33.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="36.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="27.00" y="36.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="36.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="45.00" y="36.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="36.00" width="15.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="81.00" y="36.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="18.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="24.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="33.00" y="39.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="48.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="54.00" y="39.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="39.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="75.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="81.00" y="39.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="15.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="21.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="42.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="48.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="57.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="72.00" y="42.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="18.00" y="45.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="33.00" y="45.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="42.00" y="45.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="57.00" y="45.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="69.00" y="45.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="75.00" y="45.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="15.00" y="48.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="24.00" y="48.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="39.00" y="48.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="48.00" y="48.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="57.00" y="48.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="48.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="48.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="21.00" y="51.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="39.00" y="51.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="57.00" y="51.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="51.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="81.00" y="51.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="54.00" width="12.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="54.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="39.00" y="54.00" width="27.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="69.00" y="54.00" width="12.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="54.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="18.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="24.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="33.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="39.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="45.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="54.00" y="57.00" width="12.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="69.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="60.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="21.00" y="60.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="60.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="39.00" y="60.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="60.00" width="15.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="81.00" y="60.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="63.00" width="15.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="63.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="72.00" y="63.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="78.00" y="63.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="63.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="66.00" width="21.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="45.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="54.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="66.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="72.00" y="66.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="69.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="54.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="72.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="72.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="18.00" y="72.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="72.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="45.00" y="72.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="54.00" y="72.00" width="24.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="81.00" y="72.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="75.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="18.00" y="75.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="75.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="42.00" y="75.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="54.00" y="75.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="75.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="72.00" y="75.00" width="12.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="78.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="18.00" y="78.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="78.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="78.00" width="12.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="51.00" y="78.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="57.00" y="78.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="72.00" y="78.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="81.00" y="78.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="81.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="30.00" y="81.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="81.00" width="15.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="54.00" y="81.00" width="12.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="69.00" y="81.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="12.00" y="84.00" width="21.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="36.00" y="84.00" width="9.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="51.00" y="84.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="60.00" y="84.00" width="6.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="75.00" y="84.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
      <rect x="84.00" y="84.00" width="3.00" height="3.00" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

You may need to change a few things so that you can target your source SVGs correctly, but this should give you a good jumping off point.

boarder+qr.svg

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg8" version="1.1" height="110" width="110">
  <defs id="defs2"/>
  <metadata id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
        <dc:title/>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g id="layer1">
    <path id="rect1379" d="m 0,0 h 110 v 110 H 0 Z 0" style="        stroke:#FFFFFF;        stroke-width:0.89999998;        stroke-linecap:round;        stroke-linejoin:round;        stroke-miterlimit:4;        stroke-dasharray:none;        stroke-dashoffset:0;        stroke-opacity:1"/>
  </g>
<svg:g id="barcode" fill="#000000" transform="translate(5.0,5.0)">
      <svg:rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="12.00" width="21.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="12.00" width="12.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="54.00" y="12.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="12.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="12.00" width="21.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="45.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="51.00" y="15.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="15.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="18.00" y="18.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="39.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="51.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="57.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="72.00" y="18.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="18.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="18.00" y="21.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="45.00" y="21.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="57.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="72.00" y="21.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="21.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="18.00" y="24.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="45.00" y="24.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="72.00" y="24.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="24.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="27.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="48.00" y="27.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="27.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="30.00" width="21.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="42.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="48.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="54.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="30.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="30.00" width="21.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="33.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="57.00" y="33.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="36.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="27.00" y="36.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="36.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="45.00" y="36.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="36.00" width="15.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="81.00" y="36.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="18.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="24.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="33.00" y="39.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="48.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="54.00" y="39.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="39.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="75.00" y="39.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="81.00" y="39.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="15.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="21.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="42.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="48.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="57.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="72.00" y="42.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="42.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="18.00" y="45.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="33.00" y="45.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="42.00" y="45.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="57.00" y="45.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="69.00" y="45.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="75.00" y="45.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="15.00" y="48.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="24.00" y="48.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="39.00" y="48.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="48.00" y="48.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="57.00" y="48.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="48.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="48.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="21.00" y="51.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="39.00" y="51.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="57.00" y="51.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="51.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="81.00" y="51.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="54.00" width="12.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="54.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="39.00" y="54.00" width="27.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="69.00" y="54.00" width="12.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="54.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="18.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="24.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="33.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="39.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="45.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="54.00" y="57.00" width="12.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="69.00" y="57.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="60.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="21.00" y="60.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="60.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="39.00" y="60.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="60.00" width="15.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="81.00" y="60.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="63.00" width="15.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="63.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="72.00" y="63.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="78.00" y="63.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="63.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="66.00" width="21.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="45.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="54.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="66.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="72.00" y="66.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="66.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="69.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="54.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="72.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="69.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="72.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="18.00" y="72.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="72.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="45.00" y="72.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="54.00" y="72.00" width="24.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="81.00" y="72.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="75.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="18.00" y="75.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="75.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="42.00" y="75.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="54.00" y="75.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="75.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="72.00" y="75.00" width="12.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="78.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="18.00" y="78.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="78.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="78.00" width="12.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="51.00" y="78.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="57.00" y="78.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="72.00" y="78.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="81.00" y="78.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="81.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="30.00" y="81.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="81.00" width="15.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="54.00" y="81.00" width="12.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="69.00" y="81.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="12.00" y="84.00" width="21.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="36.00" y="84.00" width="9.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="51.00" y="84.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="60.00" y="84.00" width="6.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="75.00" y="84.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
      <svg:rect x="84.00" y="84.00" width="3.00" height="3.00"/>
   </svg:g>
</svg>
```